# profile:edit on EE 2.7.2 and mySQL 5.6 can't install

Tags: database, mysql

Tried to contact mightybigrobot a few times but impossible to get a hold after buying their plugin profile:edit.

It trows an error when I'm tryign to install the default templates. 
EE 2.7.2 , mySQL 5.6 in strict mode (which should be fine - the plugin developers just need to get their plugins updated)

I'm getting this error.

```
INSERT INTO `exp_channels` (`channel_name`, `channel_title`, `channel_url`, `channel_description`, `channel_lang`, `total_comments`, `last_comment_date`, `cat_group`, `status_group`, `deft_status`, `search_excerpt`, `deft_category`, `deft_comments`, `channel_require_membership`, `channel_max_chars`, `channel_html_formatting`, `channel_allow_img_urls`, `channel_auto_link_urls`, `channel_notify`, `channel_notify_emails`, `comment_url`, `comment_system_enabled`, `comment_require_membership`, `comment_use_captcha`, `comment_moderate`, `comment_max_chars`, `comment_timelock`, `comment_require_email`, `comment_text_formatting`, `comment_html_formatting`, `comment_allow_img_urls`, `comment_auto_link_urls`, `comment_notify`, `comment_notify_authors`, `comment_notify_emails`, `comment_expiration`, `search_results_url`, `show_button_cluster`, `rss_url`, `enable_versioning`, `max_revisions`, `default_entry_title`, `url_title_prefix`, `live_look_template`, `field_group`, `site_id`) VALUES ('member_profiles', 'Member Profiles', '', '', 'en', '0', '0', '', '1', 'open', '', '', 'n', 'y', '', 'all', 'y', 'y', 'n', '', '', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', '5000', '0', 'y', 'xhtml', 'safe', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', '', '0', '', 'y', '', 'n', '10', '', '', '0', 18, '1') Filename: F:\Websites\xxxxxxx\sys\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 330
```

Anybody has any suggestions ? please , hope so.